# Read registry key which has space in batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to read the registry key which has space in it. If I read, how can I skip the REG_SZ in the output.

I tried

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('%SystemRoot%\system32\REG.exe QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-9.0" /v "Base Directory"  ^| find /i "REG_SZ"') DO set pghome=%%B
echo %pghome% 
cd /d %pghome%
```

Output is

```
C:\Users\test>set pghome=%B
C:\Users\test>echo %B
%B
C:\Users\test>cd /d %B
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

How can I read the path from the registry and navigate to it

Comment: do you execute this from command line or from a batch file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are reading the line with the required value filtering for the `REG_SZ`, you will get a line as (sorry i've not postgresql to test)

```
Base Directory    REG_SZ    C:\ProgramFiles\ .....
```

Since `for /f` command is by default using spaces (and more characters) as separators, what you have is a line with, at least, 4 tokens: `Base`, `Directory`, `REG_SZ`, `C:\...` and if the value contains spaces, aditional tokens will be available.

What is needed is all information from 4th and following tokens, so the better option will be

```
for /f "tokens=3,*" %%a in ....
```

That way, `%%a` will hold `REG_SZ` and `%%b` the rest of the line.